# Как сохранить состояние веб-страницы при перезагрузке?

Tags: javascript, html, html5, камера, android-camera

Для получения изображения с камеры смартфона на веб-странице я использую стандартный HTML-тэг `<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="environment">` и дальше передаю изображение на сервер.

Но иногда при открытии приложения камеры смартфон просто-напросто выгружает страничку из памяти, и я теряю все изменения которые сделал юзер.

Может есть способ запретить браузеру или ОС выгружать вэб-страницу из памяти или при перезагрузке страницы не терять контекст приложения?

Посоветуйте пожалуйста, хоть приблизительно, в какую сторону копать..

Comment: Отследить все проведённые изменения на странице и сохранить их в какой-нибудь localStorage, а при перезагрузке прочитать обратно из localStorage, например

Answer (score 0):

Видел подобное решение в одном проекте на [Angular2](https://angular.io/). Код на TypeScript, если вырезать типизацию, заработает и в современных браузерах без транспиляции

> `createLsManager.ts`

```
export const createLsManager = (STORADE_KEY: string) => new class {
    getValue(): string {
        return localStorage.getItem(STORADE_KEY) || '';
    }
    setValue(value: string) {
        if (value) {
            localStorage.setItem(STORADE_KEY, value.toString());
        } else {
            localStorage.removeItem(STORADE_KEY);
        }
    }
}();

export default createLsManager;
```

> `index.ts`

```
import createLsManager from "../../utils/createLsManager";

const sessionIdManager = createLsManager('MYAPP_SESSION_ID');

class MyStorage {
  get sessionId() {
    return sessionIdManager.getValue();
  }
  set sessionId(v: string) {
    sessionIdManager.setValue(v);
  }
}
```